# If I have additional damage effects from an attack, do resistances apply again?

Tags: dnd-4e, ranger, damage-resistance

I am playing a Ranger in dnd 4e, and have chose ruthless punisher for my paragon path. As per ruthless punisher:

"Most Dangerous Prey (11th level): Against
any humanoid target designated as your quarry,
you gain a bonus to damage rolls equal to your
Wisdom modifier."

Our current DM really likes creating and adding enemies with resistance to all damage. My DM is applying damage resistance to my attack, and then to my Hunter's Quarry, and then to my ruthless punisher damage separately. I believe that he is correct to apply it again to Hunter's Quarry, but incorrect to apply the resistance again to my bonus from Most Dangerous Prey. Am I correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Resistance applies once per attack. Hunter's Quarry and Most Dangerous Prey should not be resisted separately.

From Player's Handbook 1, p104 (*emphasis mine*):

> **Hunter's Quarry**
>   ... Once per round, you deal *extra damage* to your quarry. The extra damage is based on your level. If you can make multiple attacks in a round, you decide which attack to apply the extra damage to after all the attacks are rolled. ...

Note that quarry damage is considered *extra* damage.

From Martial Power 1, p66 (*emphasis mine*):

> **Most Dangerous Prey**
>   Against any humanoid target designated as your quarry, you gain a *bonus to damage rolls* equal to your Wisdom modifier.

Note that MDP damage is considered a *bonus* to damage rolls.

From the Rules Compendium, p222 (*emphasis mine*):

> **Damage Rolls**
>   When most attacks deal damage, they do so through a damage roll: a roll of dice to determine damage. Whenever a power or other effect requires a damage roll, it specifies which dice to roll and how many of them. For instance, an attack might indicate that it deals 2d8+4 damage on a hit. When a creature hits with that attack, roll 2 eight-sided dice *and add 4* to determine how much damage it deals.
>
> *A damage roll can be modified by a number of factors.* ... The following bonuses are *the most common* for an adventurer's damage rolls:
>
> - *A specific ability modifier.* ...
> - An enhancement bonus.
> - A feat bonus.
> - An item bonus.
> - A power bonus.

A *bonus* to a damage roll is **part of the damage roll.** It is **not** a separate source of damage.

From the Rules Compendium, p223 (*emphasis mine*):

> **Extra Damage**
>   Many powers and other effects grant the ability to deal extra damage. *Extra damage is always in addition to other damage* and is of the same type or types as that damage, unless otherwise noted. Because of this rule, an effect that deals no damage cannot deal extra damage.

Extra damage is *in addition* to other damage; it's bonus damage that you get as long as you dealt at least 1 damage.

When you an attack an enemy, all of the bonus damage and extra damage for the attack gets added to the attack's damage roll; the total damage for that damage roll is dealt to the target, and resisted, as a lump sum. Resistance is applied once to the attack, not once to each separate game element adding damage to the attack.

You should discuss how resistance is handled with your DM. If this approach is specifically intended to limit *your* damage, it's worth pointing out that rangers are strikers: their entire purpose is dealing damage, and they don't have much else to offer during combat, so you *should* be dealing significantly more damage than other non-striker player characters.

If your DM chooses to stick with their (incorrect) interpretation of resistance, then you should invest in a source of resist all yourself. Monsters don't get as many bonuses to damage as player characters do, but it will still be applied multiple times to some attacks by your DM's rules.